# JFrame doesn't show

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have the next problem: I'm calling a class from my Main, that have to show a JFrame. I can't even continue with my program because when I try to run it, the JFrame doesn't show.
I'm using Eclipse.

Main:

```
package System;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.awt.Menu;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Menu();

    }   
}
```

Second class:

```
package System;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Menu {

    private JFrame ventana = new JFrame("Sistema de Productos Químicos");
    private JButton sup = new JButton("Supervisor");
    private JButton oper = new JButton("Operario");

    Menu()
    {
        ventana.setSize(500,500);
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ventana.add(sup);
        ventana.add(oper);

        ventana.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It should work, and in fact displays a JFrame when I try to run it. Are you seeing any error messages when you try to run it? Have you tried running it with the Eclipse debugger to see what gets called when the program runs? Note that when you do get it to run, you'll note that you see only one JButton, the oper JButton since it fills the JFrame's contentPane since the contentPane uses BorderLayout. I suggest that you add your buttons to a JPanel and then add the JPanel to the JFrame.

Comment: Edit: I'm wrong as per Fast Snail, 1+ Avoid giving your classes names that clash with names of core Java classes. Also rename your package from System to system since package names should be lower-case.

Comment: As others have commented, you've broken the naming conventions with bad results.  However, there are other issues.  For example, any interaction with Swing/AWT objects **must** be on the Event Dispatch Thread.  Please read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because your jframe class name is `Menu` and you have import

```
import java.awt.Menu;
```

this create a new `awt menu` instead of your Menu class which create a jframe

```
new Menu();
```

to fix this change the name of the Menu class to something different.

for instance

```
public class MyMenu { //
```

Answer (score 0):

If you play around with System.out.println("Say something random"), which is something to do when your program is not working and it is not syntax error, you find out that the Main class is not even calling the Menu class, so that "cuts down" your area of search on what's srong, I have not found the problem, and will update the answer when I do.

Comment: Mistake on me(again): Have not read other people's answer/ comments before posting my own answer, anyways, lets make the "moral" of this answer be play around with System.out.println() in order to strip down area of search for mistake/error before asking/trying to find a solution. Helps out quite a bit when you get to more and more complex programs. :)

Comment: *"First of all, you forgot to extend JFrame on the Menu class.."*  First of all, **don't extend `JFrame` unless there is a clear case for doing so.**  There very rarely is a case for it, and certainly no case here.

Comment: OK, I'll get rid of that